# Possible to maintain base and extension functionality in one Managed package?

Tags: managed-package, package, isv

I have created a base package as a Managed package, for which we are occurring licence cost.
Now, On the Top of base base package, we have to provide advance functionality as an extension. For this as well will occurs licensing cost.

One Option: we can create two separate packages.

But I am looking for more insight on below.

Can we maintain the base and advance functionality in the same package with separate licencing cost for each?

Example:

Base Module + Advance Module --> Create in the same package

Base Module has a separate licence cost

Advance Module have a separate licence cost

Let's say 100 customers using the base module package. Out of those 50 customers want to use advance module, Can we charge them for advance module and enable the feature in the existing package?

Is it possible to do? If yes How?

Please guide.